# Bash script: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have an executable script `install_packages.sh` in `/home/etienne/admin` folder. The directory's path is added to `$PATH` variable from `/etc/bash.bashrc`. When I type `#echo $PATH` I see that the variable does contain the directory's path. However, when I try to run the script from other directories, shell says that `command not found`. From within own directory, the script runs fine if call it as `./install_packages.sh`. The script itself is ordinary - it contains only `apt-get install <package>` lines. I am really baffled

---

Output of the echo $PATH | xxd

```
0000000: 2f68 6f6d 652f 6461 6e69 656c 2f61 646d  /home/etienne/adm
0000010: 696e 3a2f 7573 722f 6c6f 6361 6c2f 7362  in:/usr/local/sb
0000020: 696e 3a2f 7573 722f 6c6f 6361 6c2f 6269  in:/usr/local/bi
0000030: 6e3a 2f75 7372 2f73 6269 6e3a 2f75 7372  n:/usr/sbin:/usr
0000040: 2f62 696e 3a2f 7362 696e 3a2f 6269 6e3a  /bin:/sbin:/bin:
0000050: 2f75 7372 2f67 616d 6573 3a2f 7573 722f  /usr/games:/usr/
0000060: 6c6f 6361 6c2f 6761 6d65 730a            local/games.
```

Comment: Please, add the output of `echo "$PATH" | xxd` to the question. Also, check that the error isn't coming from inside of the script: doesn't it call a command that's not found?

Comment: At the moment script contains only `apt-get install` lines. If I run them from the shell they work

Comment: Do you get any error while running like `./install_packages.sh` ?

Comment: No at all. That's what frustrates me.

Comment: Have you tried running `hash -r`?

Comment: You mention you run `# echo $PATH`, does that mean you are logged in as root? Are you running `echo $PATH` and `install_packages.sh` as the same user? Is either of the commands run with `sudo`?

Comment: Can you run it in other directories using full path, e.g. ``/home/etienne/admin/install_packages.sh``? And do you have the full error message the shell complains? Sometimes the script may try to call itself with ``./install_packages.sh``.

Comment: stupid question... but did you restart your shell after changing the PATH?

Comment: What happens if you copy the same file in `/home.etienne/bin`?  Does it work then?

Comment: are you typing ./install.sh or install.sh?